# SDL Mixer Strange Error Message

Tags: c++, sdl, audio

I have a Visual Studio C++ project. I've just started out with SDL, and I've already rendered images, text, and now I'm trying to play audio. This will be done with the SDL_Mixer extension library.

However, I'm having the following issue. When I run my code with the SDL_Mixer library included, I get the following popup error message:

```
The procedure entry point SDL_AudioStreamFlush could not be located in the dynamic link library...
```

What the heck does this mean? Did I do something wrong with the installation? I got SDL mixer from here:
https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14094017/637987?

Comment: Um so when I downloaded SDL_Mixer I just used the SDL_Mixer.dll that came with the download.
Basically, I downloaded the folder, modified project properties to link the library, and then copied SDL_mixer.dll to the project folder along with all of my other DLLS. So they all came from the same download!

Comment: I've played around with this some more. SDL_TTF version 1.2 (the other download on the SDL website) doesn't work either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue!
Basically, I didn't have the latest form of SDL2. (I think I had 2.0.5 or something)

By going to the SDL2 download page, I was able to get and install SDL-2.0.7, replacing the old version. Once I completed the update, I was relieved to hear my music playing!

Comment: You can go ahead and accept your own answer. Leave the question+answer up for the next person who hits the same or a similar issue.